# Is my 3d terrain moving?

Tags: java, libgdx, 3d

I generate a 3d isometric terrain with the help of [badlogicgames](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2032). I pass a perspective camera to the spriteBatch projectionMatrix, but when I move my player (perspective camera follows my player) it seems like the terrain is moving - here's some [video of my game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEMAo8F0qms&feature=youtu.be). I think the terrain should be static. I am also using decalBatch; my decals look fine - they remain in their position instead, the terrain does not.

This is part of the code where I render terrain:

```
sb.setTransformMatrix(matrix);
sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);//is perspective
sb.begin();
for(int z = 0; z < 100; z++) {
    for(int x = 0; x <80; x++) {
        sprites[x][z].draw(sb);
    }
}
sb.end()
```

here is the third person camera

```
cam.lookAt(player.getX(), 0, player.getZ());

cam.position.set(player.getX(),7f,player.getZ()-10f);

playerDecal.setPosition(player.getX(), player.getY(), player.getZ());
```

The problem is that terrain keeps moving around along with my camera's position. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: check if the matrix ( setTransformMatrix(matrix) ) is correct.

Comment: It's not clear to me from the video what artifact you're trying to correct. It looks like you're able to walk around your level in a sensible way — as your character moves right, the camera follows them so they stay centered on the screen, and the environment scrolls leftward by what looks like a reasonable corresponding amount for your character's movement. Can you annotate it in sone way to clarify what the symptoms of the problem are?

Comment: @DMGregory If you look at the plane and quads facing the camera you can see that the ground shifts in a way that the quads appear as if they are floating. Like the trees and bushes aren't rooted. Was hard for me to spot at first as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you setting the transform matrix? cam.combined is already transformed. It's a combined projection/transformation matrix.

Try add this line at the top

```
matrix.idt();
```

If that fixes it, then just delete the top line of your code, you don't need to set it unless it's been set somewhere else.